How can I import local modules "nicely" without modifying sys.path?
I've spent so long reading about the python system for packaging/importing of local modules and still haven't found a clean solution to my very basic situation.
Let's say I have a code directory and a test directory, both residing in the same directory. How can I run a test.py script within the test directory and have it import a local module from the code directory?
The only way I've found is to modify sys.path, but this solution is inelegant, easy to break, and would need to be duplicated at the top of every single test script.
I've tried sys.path, which works but is not a good solution. I've tried relative imports and absolute imports with __init__.py, but I always get a module not found error for my situation.
